# Dealing with pseudo-classes and BEM modifiers in SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to declare the pseudo-classes only once and varies the modifiers inside them to make my code less verbose?

```css
.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s linear;

  &--primary {
    &, &:link, &:visited {
      color: $color-text--primary;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $color-border--primary;
    }

    &:hover, &:active {
      color: $color-text--secondary;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $color-border--secondary;
    }
  }

  &--secondary {
    &, &:link, &:visited {
      color: $color-text--secondary;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $color-border--primary;
    }

    &:hover, &:active {
      color: $color-text--primary;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $color-border--secondary;
    }
  }

  &--noline {
    border-style: none;
  }
}
```

and the CSS

```css
.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.link--primary, .link--primary:link, .link--primary:visited {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.link--primary:hover, .link--primary:active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.link--secondary, .link--secondary:link, .link--secondary:visited {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.link--secondary:hover, .link--secondary:active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.link--noline {
  border-style: none;
}
```

Also, when declaring the markup

```js
<Link className='link link--secondary link--noline' to={`/`}>A link</Link>
```

`link--noline` doesn't apply and I don't know why

Notes:

1. return an anchor tag with same classes
2. I have a base a in my css which is already has a fallback style

Comment: Is this not just a specificity issue?

Comment: It does work https://jsfiddle.net/8xLq74yf/

Comment: If you want to make your scss less verbose, you can use a mixin to generate the css. https://codepen.io/jason-kinney/pen/AqbCi

Comment: I mean is there a way to reverse the order between the pseudo-classes and the modifiers (pseudo-classes first, then modifiers under them)?